# Hibernate search does not remove old value from lucene index when the object is deleted via an @NoRepositoryBean Jpa method

Tags: spring, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a `NoRepositoryBean` Jpa interface that has one custom jpa method called `deleteAllByIdIn(...)` which is inherited by some concrete JpaRepositories. For some reason this custom delete method is ignored by `Hibernate Search`. Whenever an entity is deleted through this custom method its value is not removed from the lucene index after the delete is done. I will explain the problem some more further down this post; but first here's the code

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface NameTranslationDao<T extends NameTranslation> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM #{#entityName} c WHERE c.id IN :translationsToDelete")
    public void deleteAllByIdIn(@Param("translationsToDelete") Set<Long> translationsToDelete);

}
```

Heres a `JpaRepository` subclass that extends this interface:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface LifeStageCommonNameTranslationDao extends CommonNameTranslationDao<LifeStageCommonNameTranslation> {

}
```

Theres another `@NoRepositoryBean` interface in-between the concrete JpaRepository and the NameTranslationDao NoRepositoryBean. That one is called `CommonNameTranslationDao` but it doesn't override the custom method in any way, so it is unlikely the cause of the problem, nevertheless heres the code of that repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonNameTranslationDao<T extends NameTranslation> extends NameTranslationDao<T> {

    @Deprecated
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("SELECT new DTOs.AutoCompleteSuggestion(u.parent.id, u.autoCompleteSuggestion) FROM #{#entityName} u WHERE u.autoCompleteSuggestion LIKE :searchString% AND deleted = false  AND (u.language.id = :preferredLanguage OR u.language.id = :defaultLanguage)")
    List<AutoCompleteSuggestion> findAllBySearchStringAndDeletedIsFalse(@Param("searchString") String searchString, @Param("preferredLanguage") Long preferredLanguage, @Param("defaultLanguage") Long defaultLanguage);

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT s.translatedName FROM #{#entityName} s WHERE s.language_id = :preferredLanguage AND s.parent_id = :parentId LIMIT 1")
    public String findTranslatedNameByParentAndLanguage(@Param("preferredLanguage") Long languageId, @Param("parentId") Long parentId);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "DELETE FROM #{#entityName} WHERE id = :id")
    void hardDeleteById(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE #{#entityName} c SET c.deleted = TRUE WHERE c.id = :id")
    void softDeleteById(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

Also, heres the code of the `LifeStageCommonNameTranslation` entity class:

```
    @Entity
    @Indexed
    @Table(
            uniqueConstraints = {
                    @UniqueConstraint(name = "UC_life_cycle_type_language_id_translatedName", columnNames = {"translatedName", "parent_id", "language_id"})
            },
            indexes = {
                    @Index(name = "IDX_lifestage", columnList = "parent_id"),
                    @Index(name = "IDX_translator", columnList = "user_id"),
                    @Index(name = "IDX_species_language", columnList = "language_id, parent_id, deleted"),
                    @Index(name = "IDX_autoCompleteSuggestion_language", columnList = "autoCompleteSuggestion, language_id, deleted")})
    public class LifeStageCommonNameTranslation extends NameTranslation<LifeStage> implements AuthorizationSubject {
    
        @Id @DocumentId
        @GenericGenerator(
                name = "sequenceGeneratorLifeStageCommonNameTranslation",
                strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
                parameters = {
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "_lifestagecommonnametranslation_hibernate_sequence"),
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "pooled"),
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "25"),
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "prefer_sequence_per_entity", value = "true")
                }
        )
        @GeneratedValue(
                strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = "sequenceGeneratorLifeStageCommonNameTranslation"
        )
        @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, name = "parentId")
        private Long id;
    
        @IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private LifeStage parent;
    
        @Field(index = NO, store = Store.YES)
        private String autoCompleteSuggestion;

//Getters and setters ommitted
```

The problem is the following: Whenever i use the inherited `deleteAllByIdIn()` method on `LifeStageCommonNameTranslationDao` then `Hibernate Search` will not remove the `autoCompleteSuggestion` field value from the `lucene index` after the entity has been deleted. If however i use the standard `deleteById()` JpaRepository method to delete the entity then the field value *is* removed from the `lucene index`.

Both the custom and the standard delete method were called within a `@Transactional` annotated method and i also called the `flush()` jpaRepository method right afterwards. I did this because I've read that this can sometimes help to update the lucene index. But in the case of `deleteAllByIdIn()` calling `flush()` afterwards did not help at all.

I already ruled out the possiblity that the problem was caused by the `spEL` expression in the SQL query. I tested this by replacing `#{#entityName}` with a concrete entity name like `LifeStageCommonTranslation` and then calling the `deleteAllByIdIn()` delete method. But the problem still persisted. The lucene index still did not remove the `autoSuggestionText` field value after the delete.

I can easily solve this problem by simply using the standard jpa method `deleteById()` but i want to know why the custom made jpa method `deleteAllByIdIn()` does not cause Hibernate search to update the lucene index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search detects entity change events happening in your Hibernate ORM `Session`/`EntityManager`. This excludes `insert`/`update`/`delete` statements that you wrote yourself in JPQL or native SQL queries.

The limitation is documented here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#limitations-changes-in-session

The workaround is documented there too:

> One workaround is to reindex explicitly after you run JPQL/SQL queries, either using the [MassIndexer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-massindexer) or [manually](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-manual).

EDIT: And of course your workaround might be valid as well, if `deleteById` loads the entity in the session before deleting it (I'm not that familiar with the internals of Spring Data JPA):

> I can easily solve this problem by simply using the standard jpa method deleteById() but i want to know why the custom made jpa method deleteAllByIdIn() does not cause Hibernate search to update the lucene index.